# JavaFX Deployment Issue

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, javafx, javafx-8

I am developing **JavaFX 8** application on **Windows 8.1 64bit** with **4GB RAM** using **Netbeans 8.0.2** Which is running with **JDK version 8u25 64bit**.

The Application Platform is **JDK version 8u25 32bit** , the problem is when I build the project the application runs normally but when I do native packaging so I can ship 32 bit JRE along with exe file for the application netbeans outputs this message and skip building native package :

"**Bundler Windows Application Image skipped because of a configuration problem: Bit architecture mismatch between FX SDK and JRE runtime.

Advice to fix: Make sure to use JRE runtime with correct bit architecture.**"

This is My Target tag from Build.xml file of the project :

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
       nativeBundles="image"
       outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
    <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>  
    <fx:platform basedir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre"/> 
    <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </fx:resources>
    <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
</fx:deploy>
```

So my qusestion is why Netbeans mismatches FX SDK version from the project Platform ? Although I have specified in the project settings to use 32 bit JDK and in the build.xml file also and How to ship the application with the **32 bit JRE?**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution in order to make native **32 bit** packaging of JavaFX 8 application on **64 bit** Windows. You have to change Netbeans Default Platform to **32 Bit (x86) JDK** so to solve the problem I did the following :-

1. Launched Notepad++ as administrator.
2. Opened `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc\netbeans.conf`
3. **Changed** (I have updated my JDK from 8u25 to 8u40)

   `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40"`

   **To**

   `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40"`
4. **Changed** Project Platform to default platform to match netbeans default platform and **Changed** platform tag in `build.xml` to

   `<fx:platform basedir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre"/>`

**And Netbeans did native packaging like a charm**

Comment: You're using bold rather much. It's not necessarily making the text any easier to read. Compare to other entries in SO in the future and adjust the dosage.